# OpenAl Beep function fails with more threads

Tags: c++, c++11, openal, beep

I tried to write a Beep function using OpenAl. But only a few threads of the function can be run. The following code fails after a while:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

#include <AL/alut.h> // OpenAl


void init_al()
{
    const char *defname = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
    ALCdevice* dev = alcOpenDevice(defname);
    ALCcontext *ctx = alcCreateContext(dev, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);
}

void exit_al()
{
    ALCcontext* ctx = alcGetCurrentContext();
    ALCdevice* dev = alcGetContextsDevice(ctx);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(0);
    alcDestroyContext(ctx);
    alcCloseDevice(dev);
}

void Beep(float freq = 440, float seconds = 0.5)
{
    init_al();
    ALuint buf;
    alGenBuffers(1, &buf);

    unsigned sample_rate = 10000;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;
    short* samples = new short[buf_size];
    if(samples == 0)
    {
        cout<< "It seems there is no more heap memory. Sorry we cannot make a beep!";
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < buf_size; i++)
        samples[i] = 32760*sin(2*M_PI*i*freq/sample_rate);

    alBufferData(buf,AL_FORMAT_MONO16,samples,buf_size,sample_rate);

    ALuint src;
    alGenSources(1,&src);
    alSourcei(src,AL_BUFFER,buf);
    alSourcePlay(src);
    alutSleep(seconds + 0.5);
    delete[] samples;
    exit_al();
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        thread t(Beep, 440,0.5);
        t.detach();
        alutSleep(0.01);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with `Beep` function? And how can I fix it?

I used this `Beep` function in a normal program where a problem occured. I  have reproduced the error in program above. The problem is that `Beeb` becomes unresponsive after a while, even if you leave it alone for a few seconds to complete its previous tasks. So it uses something up and doesn't return it. If you change 1000 to 20 nothing changes.

Comment: I don't think OpenAL will be delighted when you switch contexts - or destroy them and close the device - while it's playing. (And that should be `delete[] samples` in your thread function.)

Comment: I fixed `delete`. But still the problem persists. Also I don't think playing is interrupted, `alutSleep(seconds + 0.5);` prevents this.

Comment: You're starting several threads during that time, and they all change the current context. Move `init_al` and `exit_al` out of the threads into `main` (you only need to do them once each).

Comment: I tested that. But still a similar problem happens. I think there is a leakage somewhere.

Comment: I think you have design flaw in your code. Unless you doing some crash test for OpenAL. You have single sound device and 1000 users for it. Even 1000 threads on 8 cores is quite chalenged.

Comment: @user2029077 In normal way, I suspect, you should change 't.detach();' to 't.join();'

Comment: @SergeiNikulov: The problem was not the number of threads. Otherwise why the compiler lets me start them. I should have deleted the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I added 3 new lines to the program and placed `init_al` and `exit_al` in `main` and it seems the problem is solved now. btw, I don't know why is it necessary to place `init_al` and `exit_al` in `main` so this is just a partial answer to the question:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

#include <AL/alut.h> // OpenAl


void init_al()
{
    const char *defname = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
    ALCdevice* dev = alcOpenDevice(defname);
    ALCcontext *ctx = alcCreateContext(dev, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);
}

void exit_al()
{
    ALCcontext* ctx = alcGetCurrentContext();
    ALCdevice* dev = alcGetContextsDevice(ctx);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(0);
    alcDestroyContext(ctx);
    alcCloseDevice(dev);
}

void Beep(float freq = 440, float seconds = 0.5)
{

    ALuint buf;
    alGenBuffers(1, &buf);

    unsigned sample_rate = 10000;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;
    short* samples = new short[buf_size];
    if(samples == 0)
    {
        cout<< "It seems there is no more heap memory. Sorry we cannot make a beep!";
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < buf_size; i++)
        samples[i] = 32760*sin(2*M_PI*i*freq/sample_rate);

    alBufferData(buf,AL_FORMAT_MONO16,samples,buf_size,sample_rate);

    ALuint src;
    alGenSources(1,&src);
    alSourcei(src,AL_BUFFER,buf);
    alSourcePlay(src);
    alutSleep(seconds + 0.5);
    delete[] samples;

    alSourceStopv(1,&src); // new line
    alDeleteSources(1,&src); // new line
    alDeleteBuffers(1,&buf); // new line
}

int main()
{
    init_al();
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        thread t(Beep, 440,0.5);
        t.detach();
        alutSleep(0.01);
        cout<< i << "\n";
    }
     exit_al();
}
```